# Bash, issue with if

Tags: bash, if-statement, curl

I'm parsing the result of a curl call into a variable this way:

```
result=$(curl some curl parameters)
```

I'm then making a check:

```
if [ $result != "job completed" ];
then printf "ok"
fi
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
[: too many arguments
```

any idea why?

Comment: You should generally quote your variables to prevent word-splitting.

Answer (score 5):

It's almost certainly because you haven't stringified the result, meaning that the `[` command is being given more than three arguments.

If it contains the string `job completed`, you will end up with:

```
if [ job completed != "job completed" ] ...
```

I suggest you try:

```
if [ "$result" != "job completed" ] ...
```